# How handle multiple domain with MailGun API?

Tags: c#, mailgun

**Hi, I am using MailGun API in a web application with C# language. I would like to offer that the user can create a domain and send Emails using my application user interface. but I have many doubts and confusions that how to integrate this functionality in my application using Mailgun API. Please share our ideas and knowledge for the clear some following questions. Thanks in Advance.**

**1.)** I want to create multiple domains using API. can we use like this "PSD.technosys.com" or only it should be using "PSD.mailgun.org" for the new domain?

**2.)** Can I create use multiple times like "sha.technosys.com, vik.technosys.com etc." or it should be different("sha.com, vik.com etc."). Please, Advice if any limit for creating domain here?

**3.)** Currently, I have a test MailGun Account. So my question is that API key will be the same for all domains or it will be changed?

**4.)** If I will create a new Domain by MailGun API that time MailGun will create a default login SMTP Credentials or I need to create by MailGun API?

Answer (score 3):

1.) I want to create multiple domains using MailGun API. Can we use this "PSD.technosys.com" or only it should be using "PSD.mailgun.org" for the new domain?

**Answer--** You will want to use your custom domain and you can use subdomains as you'd like, however, you will need to create DNS records for each subdomain in your DNS host.

2.) Can I create use multiple times like "sha.technosys.com, vik.technosys.com etc." or it should be different("sha.com, vik.com etc."). Please, Advice if any limit for creating domain here?

**Answer--** Yes, you can create any subdomain you like, however, as previously stated you'll need to add DNS records for each subdomain added in Mailgun.

3.) Currently, I have a test MailGun Account. So my question is that API key will be the same for all domains or it will be changed?

**Answer--** The API Key will be account wide, however, the SMTP credentials will be per domain.

4.) If I will create a new Domain by MailGun API that time MailGun will create a default login SMTP Credentials or I need to create by MailGun API?

**Answer--** If you add a domain using Mailguns API then SMTP credentials will be applied when the domain is applied.